# Xamarin Forms WebView CanGoForward property is inaccurate on sites that utilize the History API

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am having an issue that relates to a post on GitHub. User nirbil summarizes it best:

If a website utilizes the historyApi then the WebView's CanGoBack CanGoForward are wrong.
Steps to reproduce -

1. Set the webview's source to a single page web application
2. Navigate within the application to a different url (should utilize
   the pushstate)
3. Navigate back -> CanGoForward changes to true
4. Navigate within the application again by following some link ->
   CanGoForward erroneously does not change to false

On windows this behavior can be traced to the webview's renderer - https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/WebViewRenderer.cs

Here is the original post on GitHub https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7691

A lot of ideas are suggested on how to solve the problem however, my grasp of Xamarin Forms is somewhat lacking. Any ideas on how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the source of webview to use renderer. I use the code sample on GitHub. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7691

The original:

[image]

Set the source of webview.

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Source="https://www.google.com" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></WebView>
```

Now:

[image]

This question on GitHub has been collected. You could follow it on GitHub. It would be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks Wendy for your quick reply. I'm not sure what you're displaying is the current issue. I also do not know what code sample in GitHub you are referring to.

Comment: The sample on github https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7691 provided by user nirbil.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a custom Xamarin Forms WebView with custom CanGoBack/Forward properties.
You can find the it here:
https://github.com/nirbil/XF.CanGoWebView

Following are the main bits of the solution.

CustomWebView control with new bindable properties:

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public CustomWebView() {}
    public static BindableProperty CustomCanGoForwardProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(CustomCanGoForward),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(CustomWebView),
            false,
            BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

    public static BindableProperty CustomCanGoBackProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(CustomCanGoBack),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(CustomWebView),
            defaultValue: false,
            BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

    public bool CustomCanGoForward
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(CustomCanGoForwardProperty);
        set => SetValue(CustomCanGoForwardProperty, value);
    }

    public bool CustomCanGoBack
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(CustomCanGoBackProperty);
        set => SetValue(CustomCanGoBackProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Custom WebViewRenderer on  Android:

```
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    protected override WebViewClient GetWebViewClient()
    {
        CustomWebViewClient webViewClient = new CustomWebViewClient(this);
        webViewClient.AddressChanged += AddressChanged;
        return webViewClient;
    }

    private void AddressChanged(string url)
    {
        if (Element is CustomWebView customWebView && Control != null)
        {
            customWebView.CustomCanGoBack = Control.CanGoBack();
            customWebView.CustomCanGoForward = Control.CanGoForward();
        }
    }
}
```

Android CustomWebViewClient that intercepts changes and alerts the renderer:

```
public class CustomWebViewClient: FormsWebViewClient
{
    public delegate void AddressChangedEventHandler(string url);
    public event AddressChangedEventHandler AddressChanged;
    public CustomWebViewClient(WebViewRenderer renderer) : base(renderer) {}
    public override void DoUpdateVisitedHistory(WebView view, string url, bool isReload)
    {
        base.DoUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);
        AddressChanged?.Invoke(view.Url);
    }
}
```

Custom WebViewRenderer on  UWP:

```
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    bool _registeredControl = false;
    long _goBackRegistrationToken = 0;
    long _goForwardRegistrationToken = 0;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        UnregisterControl();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        RegisterControl();
    }

    private void UnregisterControl()
    {
        if (Control != null && _registeredControl)
        {
            _registeredControl = false;
            Control.UnregisterPropertyChangedCallback(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.CanGoBackProperty, _goBackRegistrationToken);
            Control.UnregisterPropertyChangedCallback(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.CanGoForwardProperty, _goForwardRegistrationToken);
        }
    }

    private void RegisterControl()
    {
        if (Control != null && !_registeredControl)
        {
            _registeredControl = true;
            _goBackRegistrationToken = Control.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.CanGoBackProperty, new Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyPropertyChangedCallback(OnWebViewCanGoBackChanged));
            _goForwardRegistrationToken = Control.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.CanGoForwardProperty, new Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyPropertyChangedCallback(OnWebViewCanGoForwardChanged));
        }
    }

    private void OnWebViewCanGoBackChanged(Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty dp)
    {
        ((CustomWebView)Element).CustomCanGoBack = Control.CanGoBack;
    }

    private void OnWebViewCanGoForwardChanged(Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty dp)
    {
        ((CustomWebView)Element).CustomCanGoForward = Control.CanGoForward;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not sure if I'm implementing this wrong but so far this doesn't do anything in my project. I put all three classes in  the android solution. Should one go in the main project solution? What using statements do you use?

Comment: I added the full solution

Comment: So I was able to get this to run but it still has little to no effect. Looking at the GitHub code helped a lot but my CanGoBack and CanGoForward are still not firing correctly. Thank you though for the time you put into this project.